# Phonegap/ jquery mobile 'pagebeforeshow' event not working correctly for me on Android?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-pageshow

In my app there is quite a delay to load the next page after the initial login screen.

In my iOS app I was able to start an activity indicator in the pagebeforeshow event so the user can tell that the app is loading and not just a blank screen. As below

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#mainScreen", function() 
{ 

$('body').addClass('ui-loading'); 
$.mobile.loading("show", { 
text:"Loading", 
textVisible: $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text, 
theme: $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme, 
}); 
}); 

$(document).on("pageshow", "#mainScreen", function() 
{ 
$('body').removeClass('ui-loading'); 
});
```

I am having a problem displaying the spinner on android devices. I have ran the app with an alert in the pagebeforeshow event so i know that it is triggered but I can't figure out why it won't display

Comment: pagebeforeshow and pageshow is more to do with the animation on the element while yes it may work in some cases where the browser starts the animation but then doesn't return a finish until a certain stage... it also may mean android sends back something different... Try putting console.log with your addclass removeclass and see if it is actually firing at all... actually maybe not console.log ...alert? maybe or something that you can debug with on android

Comment: It is firing, but my issue now is that the indicator is only visible after the page has loaded. I'm sorry the most experienced with jquery so a lot of this is trial and error for me

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the ajaxStart event?

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have an issue showing when I am calling Ajax requests. My issue is that I have one or two pages that load slow and I want an indicator when they are loading